# CosmosDB pagination with requestContinuation not returning results

Tags: spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using JPA with CosmosDB to fetch entries from containers.
I have to implement pagination and, according to the documentation, it should rely on the **requestContinuation** string, which is null on the first request and not null afterwards.

To make things more simple, I created a basic app which calls the repository, takes the requestContinuation object and then makes a new request using it's value.

I have 8 objects in the CosmosDB container and the page size is 5. The first request returns 5 elements and the requestionContinuation value

```
{"compositeToken":"{\"token\":null,\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}","orderByItems":[{"propertyBag":{"item":[2021,5,20,14,13,52,716826900]},"item":[2021,5,20,14,13,52,716826900],"map":{"item":[2021,5,20,14,13,52,716826900]}}],"rid":"7eYNAKj8mAMIAAAAAAAAAA==","inclusive":true}
```

I use it, AS IT IS, to make a new request

```
    Pageable pageable = new CosmosPageRequest(0, size, requestContinuation, Sort.by(sort));
    return repo.findAllByUserId(userId, pageable);
```

**The result is empty and the new requestContinuation is null.** The page object correctly states that the total number is 8 but never returns the missing 3.
The value of the requestContinuation is not a valid JSON, if you analyze it. I also tried replacing the \ from the compositeToken part of the JSON, which made it a valid JSON. If the invalid JSON is accepted by CosmosDB but the result is empty, the valid JSON is rejected as being INVALID :)

I looked into various sources and I saw something about encoding. I tried to URLEncoder class but it didn't work.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The query is also sorting by the creation date. If sorting is removed, the new token works. It's structure is different.

Old token - with sorting:

```
{"compositeToken":"{\"token\":null,\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}","orderByItems":[{"propertyBag":{"item":[2021,5,20,14,13,52,716826900]},"item":[2021,5,20,14,13,52,716826900],"map":{"item":[2021,5,20,14,13,52,716826900]}}],"rid":"7eYNAKj8mAMIAAAAAAAAAA==","inclusive":true}
```

New token - no sorting:

```
{"token":"+RID:~7eYNAKj8mAMKAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:5#ISV:2#IEO:65567#QCF:4#FPC:AQoAAAAAAAAADQAAAAAAAAA=","range":{"min":"","max":"FF"}}
```

Comment: can you try to encode the continuationToken and send it to the server?

Comment: As mentioned above, I tried to encode it using URLEncode but I get a response saying that it's invalid. How should I encode it?

Comment: The problem is the sorting. I will update the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The second request, with the continuationToken, was returning an empty response because the ordering field was a LocalDateTime field, which in CosmosDB is serialized as an array. I fixed the issue by adding this to the LocalDateTime field:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

This way, the sorting field is a string and can be used for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Just Encode the Request Token and it will work like charm